# Why don't my icloud.com contacts download to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

I've manually imported my Google Contacts into icloud.com (via a vCard file). Now I'd like to have these contacts available on my iPhone. My iCloud is property set up (Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > iCloud). "Fetch New Data" is set to Push, "Contacts" switch is turned on.

Nevertheless the contacts don't sync. How can I analyze and fix this?

Comment: Did you try a restart of the phone?  Also go to Contacts and click the "group" button in the top left and make sure that "All iCloud" is checked.

Comment: @Tyson Looks like restart fixed it. Still, there should be a "Sync manually now" button.

Comment: Cool, I'll make it an answer then.  And I guess Apples theory is they don't need a manual sync button because it's not suppose to break, it's just supposed to work, but yea at least some indication that sync wasn't running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a restart of the phone?

Also go to Contacts and click the "group" button in the top left and make certain that "All iCloud" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Phone restart fixed the issue.